# Need to activate the next menu option on right click

Tags: jquery

I have already coded in the script where when a user presses the tab key the menu gets activated and moves through all the list and the drop down lists in the navigation bar by pressing the tab key.

Now i want to add another script where i want to use the right and left arrow key to move through the menu.

For eg. i am in a drop down list of a menu item by pressing the tab key(script runs on tab key press). Now when i press the right arrow key it should not shift to the next item in the drop down list rather i want to close the current drop down list and open the next menu item in the navigation bar.
i.e say the menu items are:
-Home(Main)

-Information(Main)

-About us(Dropdown list of information)

-Events(Dropdown list of information)

-HandsOut(Dropdown list of information)

-Students(Main)

Now say i am at Events in the drop down list of Information tab. Now if i click on right arrow key once the dropdown list will close and if i click right arrow twice i will shift to Students (Main). This is what i am looking for.

Here is my attempt:

```
jQuery("#check li").keydown(function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode == 37) { 
            //left
            alert('left arrow pressed!');
        }else if(e.keyCode == 39) { 
            // right
            var n= jQuery(this).attr('class');
            //alert(n);

            if(n == 'uk-parent uk-open'){
                var count= jQuery(this).index();
                //alert(count);
                var count_new= count +1;
                jQuery('.uk-parent').removeClass("uk-open");
                jQuery(".uk-parent li").eq(count_new).addClass("uk-open");
            }
            //var m=jQuery(".uk-parent .uk-open").closest('li').next().find('li .uk-parent').addClass('uk-open');
        }

});
```

The HTML :

```
<li class="uk-parent" data-uk-dropdown="{'preventflip':'y','remaintime':400}" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="2">
<a href="/information">Information</a>

<div class="uk-dropdown uk-dropdown-navbar uk-dropdown-width-1 uk-dropdown-bottom" style="min-width: 250px; max-width: 250px; width: 250px; top: 100px; left: 0px;" aria-hidden="true" tabindex="">

<div class="uk-grid uk-dropdown-grid">
<div class="uk-width-1-1">
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-navbar">
<li tabindex="3">

<a href="/information/about-us">About Us</a>
</li>
<li tabindex="4">
<a href="/information/events-calendar">Events Calendar</a>
</li>
<li tabindex="5">
<a href="/document-library-tree-view">Handouts, Forms, &amp; Flyers</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

In this script #check is the id of the main navigation bar, class=uk-open is the class which is used to open the drop down list of a menu item. uk-parent is the class of the main menu item.

Comment: Please include all relevant code, including html

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen i did add it now. Its really tough to get the exact code. If you could look into this. I tried my best to explain the situation.